# Address of Non Static member of a class prints address as 1, when access like static variable

Tags: c++, pointers, static-members

I was seeing some code and definition some where, like

```
 class A {
       public:
              int a,b;
 };

 main() {
        A a;
        std::cout<<"Test output "<<&A::a<<" "<<&A::b<<std::endl;
 }

 Output
       1 1
```

What I dont understand is a and b are not static members of A, but when they are accessed like a static member it gives an error, but when accessing the address of it like a static member prints 1. Is there a special meaning behind it, coz I have no idea why it is needed and why it works this way. Thanks.

Comment: Your `main()` has no return type ;) Also, in case you didn't know, `struct` has `public` as the default access specifier, so it would save that line/extra indentation.

Comment: yeah yeah, I know that part, i did not copy it from my cpp file, just coded the necessary lines on the fly..... and yeah the only diff btw struct and class. +1 for ur enthu...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `&A::a` when `a` is a *non-static member* returns a *pointer-to-member-object* (or *pointer-to-member-function* if `a` were a function). One can use them like this:

```
A a;
a.a = 1;
a.b = 2;

int (A::*) some_int_member_of_a = &A::a;
std::cout << a.*some_int_member_of_a; // prints 1

a.*some_int_member_of_a = 5;
std::cout << a.*some_int_member_of_a; // now prints 5
```

The stream output operation is not defined for *pointer-to-member* values, but there is a conversion from them to `bool` which is what's getting printed in your output.

Comment: @howtechstuffworks: It gives you the ability of making a _pointer to a member_ and then apply on any object of such type. They are used a lot with _binders_ and the like, you could search for things like the old _std::mem_fun_ and _std::mem_fun_ptr_ for some examples.

Comment: That's pretty cool; there's my piece of new knowledge today. I balanced that. Ever since the final sentence was added, it explicitly explains the behaviour, so it's a perfectly good, direct answer to the question.